# Why does the sum of residuals in regression through the origin need not be 0?

Tags: regression, residuals, intercept

Why does the sum of residuals in regression through the origin need not be 0?

$\sum\hat{u_i} \ne0$

I found this in the textbook.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the full quote from the textbook and the reference?

Comment: See question/solution 2.b, 2.c, 2.d. http://people.bath.ac.uk/sw283/MA20227/tut2-12.pdf

Comment: @ harre, in question/solution 2.c., is this not suitable to use regression through the origin in these data? Because upon x1=0, y1 is not zero.

Comment: It might be more fruitful to pose this question in a reverse way: what does your textbook say about why the sum of residuals is zero in ordinary least squares regression?

Comment: @ harre, that is unbiasedness. In practice, I think it is not suitable to use regression through the origin when x1 & y1 are not zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

This is implicitly answered at [Why do residuals in linear regression always sum to zero when an intercept is included?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189584/why-do-residuals-in-linear-regression-always-sum-to-zero-when-an-intercept-is-in)  and  [Do these residuals sum to zero?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308539/do-these-residuals-sum-to-zero), so refer there for details.

In short, that the sum of residuals is zero is a way of saying that the residuals vector is orthogonal to a vector of only ones. A vector of ones is used to represent the intercept.

When there is no intercept in the model, the model matrix does not contain a column vector of ones. That's the explication.