# Subtracting a constant from the OLS summation

Tags: least-squares

On a proof for the OLS of $\beta$, I have seen this step:

$\sum x_i (y_i - \alpha - \beta x_i) = \sum (x_i - k) (y_i - \alpha - \beta x_i) $ for any constant $k$.

Why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because $y_i - \alpha -\beta x_i$ is the residual $r_i$, and the sum of residuals ($\sum\limits_i r_i$) is zero (see e.g. [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189584/why-do-residuals-in-linear-regression-always-sum-to-zero-when-an-intercept-is-in)).

In this step you are just adding $k\sum (y_i - \alpha -\beta x_i)$ on the right-hand-side, that is equal to zero.