# When will point ($\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$) not go through the regression line?

Tags: regression, least-squares

It is understood that the estimated ordinary least squares (OLS) regression line will pass through the average $x$ and $y$, but if there is no intercept it will no longer pass through ($\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$). May I know what is the explanation for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a regression line must pass through a point $(h,k)$ then the slope which minimises the sum of squares of the residuals is $$\widehat\beta= \frac{\overline{(x - h) (y - k)}}{\overline{(x - h)^2}}$$

In simple linear regression, you can further minimise the sum of squares by choosing that point to be $(\bar x,\bar y)$, i.e. the regression line passes though the average point.

But if there is no intercept then you force that point to be $(0,0)$ and you get $\widehat\beta= \frac{\overline{xy}}{\overline{x^2}}$, so the regression line also passes through $\left(\bar x,  \frac{\overline{xy}}{\overline{x^2}}\bar x\right)$ and that will usually not be the average point; the sum of squares of residuals will usually be higher than than if you had flexibility over $(h,k)$

Answer (score 4):

The reason is very similar to the reason that the residual terms will equal zero.

[Why do residuals in linear regression always sum to zero when an intercept is included?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189584)

For a simple linear regression (not for OLS in general which we will show later) you have the formula:

$$y_i = \hat\alpha +  \hat\beta x_{i} + \epsilon_i$$

and for the average this becomes:

$$\bar{y_i} = \alpha + \beta \bar{x_{i}} + \bar{\epsilon_i}$$

And the OLS regression with an intercept included will be such that the residual terms $\bar{\epsilon}$ are equal to zero.

The reason is that we must have the derivatives of the residual terms equal to zero

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat\alpha} \sum \epsilon_i^2  =0$$

which will lead to

$$ \begin{array}{}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat\alpha} \sum \epsilon_i^2 &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \sum (y_i - \hat\alpha -  \hat\beta x_{i})^2\\ &=&   \sum -2 \hat\alpha (y_i - \hat\alpha +  \hat\beta x_{i})\\ &=&  -2 \hat\alpha \sum \epsilon_i  &=& 0 \end{array}$$

---

#### Intuitively

If the line does not go through the point $\bar{x},\bar{y}$ then this will be equivalent to the sum of the errors being unequal to zero, and we will be able to improve the sum of squared residuals $\sum \epsilon_i^2$ by shifting the line up or down.

When the line goes through the point $\bar{x},\bar{y}$, then a change of the parameter $\hat{\alpha}$ does not improve the fit (the derivative is zero).

[image: comparison]

---

#### It depends on the point of view

The OLS regression curve only passes necessarily through the point $\hat{x},\hat{y}$ when you have *linear* regression. For OLS that is used to express a non-linear function with an intercept term you will still have the situation that the sum of residuals will be equal to zero, but you do not have anymore the relationship $$\bar{y_i} = \alpha + \beta \bar{x_{i}} + \bar{\epsilon_i}$$

An example is a quadratic cuvre

[image: quadratic fit]

However, you could express this regression of $y$ with a quadratic curve (which is seemingly a non-linear function) as a linear function of $x$ and $x^2$ by means of viewing it as multivariate linear regression. Then it will *also* pass through the means.

$$\bar{y_i} = \alpha + \beta_1 \overline{x_{i}} + \beta_2 \overline{x_{i}^2} + \bar{\epsilon_i}$$

because now you express it as a multidimensional case.

[image]

Comment: +1 Very clear and insightful, thank you.