# Do these residuals sum to zero?

Tags: regression, least-squares, residuals, error

$\epsilon =\sum (y_i-\beta x_i)$

$\beta = \frac {\sum x_iy_i}{\sum x_i^2}$

---

$\sum y_i - \frac {\sum x_iy_i}{\sum x_i^2}\sum x_i=0$?

Is the sum equal zero or not? I only know that $\sum y_i =n\bar y$ and $\sum x_i =n\bar x$ but what to do with the fraction term?

Comment: Juggling the terms around you should be able to get a relevant consequence of that equality. You can then try to work out if that consequence holds in general or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The residuals are perpendicular to the regressor vectors $x_{j,i}$. That means for each $j$ we have: 
  $$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x_{j,i} \epsilon_i = 0$$

**So if one of the regressors vectors, say $x_{1,i}$, is an intercept term** (that means $x_{1,i} = 1$, or a constant instead of 1, for all $i$) then we *always* have:
  $$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} \epsilon_i = 0$$ 
which means that **then the residuals sum to zero**.

If this is **not** the case (as is your case), then the residuals do not *necessarily* sum to zero.

You will get:

$$\sum \epsilon_i = \sum y_{i} - \beta_1  \sum x_{1,i} - \beta_2  \sum x_{2,i} -... - \beta_{k-1}  \sum x_{k-1,i} - \beta_k  \sum x_{k,i}$$

In your case when there is only a single regressor

$$\sum \epsilon_i = \sum y_{i} - \beta_1  \sum x_{1,i}$$

which is only zero iff

$$\frac{\sum y_{i}}{\sum x_{i}}=  \frac{\sum x_{i} y_i  }{\sum x_{i}^2}$$

(where we applied a division, possibly by zero, so also the case $\sum x_{i} = \sum y_{i} = 0$, counts)