# Linear regression problem: how do I prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_{i} - \hat{Y}_{i}) = 0$?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

If $\textbf{X}\in\textbf{R}^{n\times p}$ has full rank and $\textbf{Y}\in\textbf{R}^{n\times 1}$, prove that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_{i} - \hat{Y}_{i}) = 0
\end{align*}

where $\hat{\textbf{Y}}$ is the fitted value of the linear model $\textbf{Y} = \textbf{X}\beta + \textbf{e}$, $\textbf{e}\sim\mathcal{N}_{n}(\textbf{0},\sigma^{2}\textbf{I}_{n})$. Precisely speaking, $\hat{\textbf{Y}} = \textbf{X}\hat{\beta}$ such that $\textbf{X}^{\prime}\textbf{X}\hat{\beta} = \textbf{X}^{\prime}\textbf{Y}$. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: the first column of $\mathbf{X}$ is all $1$'s

Comment: Sorry, I still did not grasp the idea. Can you provide a full answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do these residuals sum to zero?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308539/do-these-residuals-sum-to-zero)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\X}{\mathbf{X}}\newcommand{\Y}{\mathbf{Y}}\newcommand{\bhat}{\hat{\beta}}\newcommand{\yhat}{\hat{\Y}}\newcommand{\0}{\mathbf{0}}$We know that $$\X'\Y =\X'\X\bhat,$$ so rearranging this, we have
$$\X'\left(\Y - \X\bhat\right) = \0,\quad  \text{i.e.}\quad \X'\left(\Y - \yhat\right) =\0.$$
Looking at the first component of both sides, we get (since the top row of $\X'$ is all $1$'s) using the definition of matrix multiplication that
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}1\cdot \left(Y_i - \hat{Y}_i\right)=0,$$
which is the desired result.